# How to destructure RouteParams with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I've followed this [guide](https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/object-destructuring-in-typescript/) for destructuring objects in TypeScript.

```
interface Params {
  year: string
  month: string
}
const { year, month }: Params = route.params
```

and yet TypeScript is complaining:

```
TS2739: Type 'RouteParams' is missing the following properties from type 'Params': year, month
```

RouteParams type is not defined by me, it comes from vue-router.d.ts:

```
export declare type RouteParams = Record<string, RouteParamValue | RouteParamValue[]>;
```

so of course it doesn't have `year` and `month` params, however I am certain these params will be available at the moment of code execution. Not sure how to make TypeScript accept these params. If I try:

```
const { year, month }: Params = route.params as Params
```

I get:

> TS2352: Conversion of type 'RouteParams' to type 'Params' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a type cast to unknown first:

const { year, month } = route.params as unknown as Params